# How to start making application in Android Device to retrieve data from BarCode Reader?

Tags: android, barcode

I got a android device (running lolipop) with a Bar code reader Attached to it.
I do not have any API's from the manufacturer on how to retrieve Bar-codes , however the device does works and retrieves data from the application given by default from the manufacturer.

I just want to gather information before proceeding any further but i cannot find any help online (GOOGLE.. probably i am not searching correctly).

I basically want to create some application or use any available application that can retrieve information from the barcode on click of the scan button ('This scan button is a physical button on device' ) and send it as keystroke to  any input text field in browser (native android browser or Google chrome ).

Any Suggestions on how to procced will be highly appreciated .

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html refer this link, It may give you more appropriate way..

Comment: Usually there are custom APIs to connect to an integrated barcode reader on an Android device. Would be helpful to know the brand of the device. [Zebra Technologies provide this kind of APIs for their devices](https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/emdk).

Comment: I am using "rugged-handheld-pda-bh84" 

Is there some generic API that can be used

http://www.batlgroup.net/rugged-handheld-pda-bh84/